# Java8-JUnit5: Why does assert raise some exception about an ArrayList (am I using it correctly)?

Tags: java, exception, assert, junit-jupiter

I am starting to use the `assert` keyword instead of writing conditional exception `raise`.
I am not sure I am using `assert` correctly, because, when tests fail, the exception talks about some ArrayList (I am not using that here).

Here's some code to reproduce the error:

```
public class ThisTest {
    @Test
    public void myTest () {
        assert 1==2 : "nope";
    }
}
```

So, I am getting my AssertionError, as expected, but there's also this stuff in the end (showing you the whole output):

```
java.lang.AssertionError: nope

at com.blah.ThisTest.myTest(ThisTest.java:8)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

What ArrayList is this talking about, maybe I am missing a parameter?

Comment: The assert statement throws an `AssertionError`, resulting in the stack trace being output. The stack trace includes methods that have called your test method, `ThisTest`. The JUnit framework puts all test methods in an ArrayList and then executes each one in turn. Hence the ArrayList in the stack trace.

Comment: BTW, it's more common to use the assert functions of JUnit itself, not Java's assert mechanism, e.g. `assertEquals("nope", 1, 2)`. The error message you get would tell you that the expected number is 1 and the actual number was 2.

Answer (score -1):

The lines after the exception are called a “stack trace”. The top line is where the exception occurred. The next line down is where the method containing the top line was called. Likewise for the remaining lines of the stack trace.

Most of the time errors are caused by the values that are passed in. So to resolve the issue one must walk down the stack trace, determining at each line how incorrect parameters were created.

In other words JUnit called the forEach method on an ArrayList, resulting in a call to your program.

In your case the stack trace is not helpful, since it is in library. Stack traces are a lot more helpful when they are pointing to locations in your own code.

If you would like to see for yourself write some simple classes and have them call each other, ending in a method that just throws a RuntimeException. Then run it and compare the lines in your code to the stack trace. It will all become clear.

Comment: I wasn't asking about stack traces; I was asking about this particular exception from JUnit. I guess I could download the sources and debug JUnit for a week (and that's assuming the complexity of what I will encounter isn't above my IQ)... But that's true for all the questions in SO ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).